# Galois group of $x^4-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: galois-theory

I factored $x^4-5$ into $(x-\sqrt[4]{5})(x+\sqrt[4]{5})(x-i\sqrt[4]{5})(x+i\sqrt[4]{5})$, determining the roots: $x=\pm\sqrt[4]{5}$ and $x=\pm i\sqrt[4]{5}$. The $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $x^4-5$ are the identity automorphism, the one exchanging $\sqrt[4]{5}$ and $-\sqrt[4]{5}$ and the one exchanging $i\sqrt[4]{5}$ to $-i\sqrt[4]{5}$.

Now, how do I go on to find the Galois group? I found an explanation about the Galois group being isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but I would love to have a more profound explanation of why.

(I am a high school student seeking some insight on Galois theory for my high school thesis on the roots of polynomials.)

Comment: Just a comment: intuitively, since the four roots form a regular square centered at the origin of $\Bbb C$, I would expect the Galois group to be the group of symmetries of a square. The group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon is called a *dihedral group*, and has order $2n$, in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ for the following reason:

The splitting field for $f(x) = x^4-5$ is $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}, i]$.  We have the tower of fields $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}] \subset K$.  We have $[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$, and since $i \notin \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]$, then $x^2+1$ is irreducible in this field, so we must have $[K:\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]] = 2$. (See footnote)

Therefore, $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = [K:\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]:\mathbb{Q}] = 8$.  Recall that the order of $\operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})$ is equal to the degree of the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $|\operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})| = 8$.  Further, since $f$ has $4$ roots, we have $\operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q}) \subset S_4$.  Note that subgroups of order $8$ inside of $S_4$ are Sylow $2$-subgroups, and all Sylow $p$-subgroups are isomorphic to each other for a given $p$, so it will suffice to simply find a single subgroup of order $8$ inside of $S_4$ and classify it.

Alternatively, you can list the automorphisms by hand, and you'll know your list is exhaustive once you've written down $8$ of them, then compare to groups you're already familiar with (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_8, \  \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, \ D_4, \ \mathcal{Q}_8$, etc).

---

**Footnote**: The degree of an extension $F[\alpha]$ over $F$ is equal to the degree of an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ with $\alpha$ as a root. So for example, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]$ is a degree $4$ extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\sqrt[4]{5}$ is a root of $g(x) = x^4-5$, which is an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Actually, you could refine the tower to $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]\subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]5]\subset K$.

Comment: The keyword $2$-Sylow group might be worth mentioning as well ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Forgive my ignorance: what would be the point of considering the refined tower when the goal was simply to determine the order of the Galois group?  Further, are you hinting that since the Galois group will be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$, and all such subgroups are isomorphic to each other, then it suffices to simply classify a single subgroup of order $8$ inside $S_4$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am afraid I lost you at the third line. How does one compute the dimension?

Comment: @CauchytheDog, if one has a tower of fields $F \subset E \subset K$, then it is a fact that $[K:F] = [K:E] \cdot [E:F]$.  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees
Feel free to ask more questions if anything else is unclear.

Comment: @CauchytheDog, I realized that you may've been asking about something else, so I added a footnote just in case.

Comment: So then the answer would be: $\text{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})\cong D_4$, since $D_4$ is the only subgroup of $S_4$ with order 8?

Comment: @CauchytheDog, indeed!